# Add Stripe library to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I need to add the Stripe third party library to Wordpress for using custom payment with checkout.

I want to install a variable payment for my customer. For the moment, I use a plugin, but it's not enough flexible (hard coded amount).

Do I have to create my own plugin to do that? Is there not a more simple way?

When I download the library, I get a lot of files, do I need all of them, or do I have to pick the files I need? Do I really need to learn component to achieve this?

I have read so many things on Internet about installing a third party library on Wordpress that I'm lost now.

Thank you!